# MySQLi get results and create key value array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli, key-pair

I want to build an array with key-value pairs of MySqli query. What I have so far overwrites array's entries:

```
$array = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $difference = abs($base - $row["sql_number"]);
        $array = [$difference => $row["sql_number"]];
        $bar = each($array);
        print_r($bar);
    }

    echo count($array);
    ksort($array);
    echo count($array);

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {             
        echo "Key: ".$key;
        echo "Value: ". $value;
    }
```

`print_r($bar);` prints the key-value pairs correct but I am convinced it is because it just prints the latest entry from the `mysqli_fetch_array($result)` and the previous entries are overwriten. 
I want to create such an array then sort it with `ksort` by the key value.

Comment: you made a typo here `foreach ($arrayas` which should read as `foreach ($array as`. If that is your real code, error reporting would have thrown an undefined arrayas variable notice. If you are using `foreach ($array as`, please fix your question.

Comment: Since you don't want to override the value, try `$array[] = [$difference => $row["sql_number"]];`. This will prevent same `difference` from being overridden too, but note that in the next `foreach` the `value` will be an `array`. Can you post the desired structure of the final array?

Comment: @Fred-ii- fixed. Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome Lenny.

Comment: @FirstOne i have made changes according to your suggestion but now when I want to access the key value at my foreach loop it gives me an error: `Array to string conversion`. I gues that this technique builds array of arrays?

Comment: That's why I asked for the desired structure of the array ^^. Replace `echo "Value: ". $value;` with `print_r($value);` just so you can see the results. Yes, you'll have arrays inside your `$array`. _Edit:_ what should happen if you have two `differences` that are the same?

Comment: So now i got rid of the error message but it seems that `ksort()` does not sort the array by the key value ascending..

Comment: Ok, so try `$array[$difference] = $row["sql_number"];` instead. (You can use `echo "Value: ". $value;` instead of `print_r` with this).

Comment: Excellent! Please post it as an asnwer so we could save it clearly for the others!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were right about your assumptions. Since you have the `print_r` inside the loop, even though it's replacing the value each time, you are also printing it each time.

This line:

```
$array = [$difference => $row["sql_number"]];
```

Should be like this:

```
$array[$difference] => $row["sql_number"];
```

That way, you'll keep track of the previous values (`keys`) and add new ones.

---

This example shows the problem:

```
$a = array('ok' => 'fine');
$b['ok'] = 'fine';

print_r($a); // Array ( [ok] => fine ) 
echo '<br>';
print_r($b); // Array ( [ok] => fine )
echo '<br><br>';

$a = array('ok2' => 'fine2');
$b['ok2'] = 'fine2';

print_r($a); // Array ( [ok2] => fine2 ) 
echo '<br>';
print_r($b); // Array ( [ok] => fine [ok2] => fine2 ) 
echo '<br><br>';
```

---

I just feel like mentioning that you **CAN'T FORGET** that this will **override** previous `differences`. *In this case*, same `$row["sql_number"]`-s will produce same differences, so it **might** not be a problem. It's still worth mentioning. Example of this problem:

```
$b['ok'] = 'fine';
print_r($b); // Array ( [ok] => fine )     

echo '<br><br>';

$b['ok'] = 'fine2';
print_r($b); // Array ( [ok] => fine2 )
```